# Is there a function/way in oracle sql to collect all the data from a column and turn it into a row according to an id?

Tags: sql, oracle

with a simplified example I would have a database with IDs(and other values that are the same like names etc) and would have a list of cars they own

```
   ---------------
   | Id | Value  |
   ---------------
   | 1  | BMW    |
   | 1  | Skoda  |
   | 1  | Lada   |
   | 2  | Audi   |
   | 2  | Fiat   |
   ---------------
```

What I would like to achieve is

```
   ---------------------------------------
   | Id | Column1  | Column2  | Column3  |
   ---------------------------------------
   | 1  | BMW      | Skoda    |  Lada    |
   | 2  | Audi     | Fiat     | (empty)  |
   ---------------------------------------
```

So far I tried using Pivot but only managed to flip the values not collect them so I imagine maybe it should be put in a sub-query somehow I just couldn't figure out how

Comment: Show us the `pivot` you tried.  That appears to be what you want so it's hard to know what your issue is.  How do you sort the rows to know which value goes in `column1` vs `column2` or `column3`?

Comment: What if an ID has four cars? Ten cars? A hundred cars? The variable number of possible columns will be a problem. Instead, consider something like [`list_agg`](https://database.guide/listagg-function-in-oracle/) to turn all the cars into a single column separated list. *What's the purpose of doing is transform?* There may be a better way.

Comment: Maybe the car example was not really good excuse my English, point of this should be that there are services for medical issues, they went for a check-up,for an MRI and so on and I'd like the data for those in a row beside their name instead of having 3 or more lines of the exact same person (messes with count)
So pivoting might not be the best as I not just want to turn it into a row but group them if their id is the same. I am mainly developing in C# and I know how to do it there, but they want it in an excel which I have no idea if even possible in sql alone that is why I am asking

Comment: Short answer is "No", but yet you can [check out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle%2bdynamic-pivot?tab=Frequent) in order to reach workarounds.

Comment: Thank you! That already helps a lot